# What is the difference between requiring an SSL cert and accepting an SSL cert?

Tags: ssl, https

So I know the fundamental difference between requiring an SSL cert and accepting, one means you must have an SSL certificate and the other means you don't need one.

In my IIS Manager for a certain webpage I have the this setup: [image]

The issue that I am having is that when I set Require SSL Cert and have Client certificates set to accept/ignore I can only get to webpage using HTTPS. Now if I change it to Require, I can no longer access the webpage, even with HTTPS... so I am just trying to figure out what the difference is, and how it effects the webpage.

So maybe my question is phrased wrong... I'm not sure, my understanding on the subject is fairly limited, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this article explains it clearly. **IIS and client certificates**
[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907274](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907274)

Comment: @nspire looks like the link is dead.

Comment: It should be Ignore, *Request,* Require.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Client-certificate authentication can be optional or mandatory, or not used at all.

- *Ignore* is when it's not used at all.
- *Accept* will take a certificate if it's presented, but will also continue with connections where the client doesn't present one.
- *Require* only continues with connections that have a client certificate.

Client-certificate authentication is something that can only be initiated by the server in SSL/TLS, so this terminology isn't quite correct, but that's what's used in IIS.

Comment: So, for me... I have a checkout page that then moves on to credit card info and everything that a normal checkout page would have... I have it so SSL is required, but would suggest also having the CCA required as well?

Comment: "Require SSL" just means it will only let the client access this application via `https://` (and possibly try to upgrade from `http://` to `https://` if not, but this is [not a complete solution](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)). This is rather independent of the client certificate settings. (If you're not using client certs, just choose ignore.)

Comment: Ok. I guess what I am really trying to ask is do you think I should be using client certs as well (for credit card payment) or is SSL enough?

Comment: Generally speaking, your users are unlikely to have a client certificate.

Comment: I recall seeing somewhere that it is possible to generate a client certificate for a user (which for our website in order to place an order they have to be signed into their account). If it was possible, do you think it is unnecessary?

Comment: It's possible, but it can bring more complications. You'd have to use or set up a CA for that (alternatives can be a bit more complex too). I don't know of any e-commerce site that use them.

Comment: Do we really require `Require SSL ` flag to enable SSL communication? Or it is required only when we consider client certificates?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan Require SSL is required only when we consider client certificates for authN/authZ purpose.

Comment: @Viku Probably not. Require SSL would be to require SSL/TLS whether or not client certificates are used. It's the following 3 options (under "Client certificates") that are related to client-cert authnz.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer given by @Bruno. These values can be set in `applicationHost.config`-file or even `web.config` if override is allowed.

The attribute is called `sslFlags` and you will find the possible values as well as an example below.

```
None                Disable SSL.
Ssl                 Require SSL.
SslNegotiateCert    Accept client certificates for authentication.
SslRequireCert      Require clients certificates for authentication.
SslMapCert          Enable certificate mapping authentication.
Ssl128              Require 128-bit SSL.
```

Example for a site named Contoso that requires HTTPS and a client certificate trusted by the server:

```
<location path="Contoso">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <access sslFlags="Ssl,SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert">
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access