# HTTP vs HTTPS what is the difference and what is actually going on with SSL?

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, https, iis-8

I had asked a question a while back about [What is the difference between requiring an SSL cert and accepting an SSL cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19383538/1887101)

For the most part that cleared up the differences between the two, however I am still a little unclear on the topic.

[image: SSL Settings]

I have a few questions about this image:

- **Require SSL** - What exactly does this mean from a client standpoint? Does it mean that in order for the webpage to appear the server needs to have an SSL certificate? How does this encryption work?
- **Client Certificates** - I get that this all comes from the client, but is it something that I, as a webserver, would issue? What would be a particular situation where you would require a Client certificate?

Was also reading this article: [Why SSL? The Purpose of using SSL Certificates](https://www.sslshopper.com/why-ssl-the-purpose-of-using-ssl-certificates.html)
and while I do have Require SSL and Ignore Client certificates setup on specific pages, I don't see the below changes to the address bar:

[image: address bar]

- **Why do I not see that?** What is required of me in order to get that working, because that leads me to believe there really isn't anything more secure with using HTTPS as opposed to HTTP

The reason that I am questioning this is because recently, when trying to dynamically load HTML into my website I was doing the loading using Javascript and HTTPS for the url, but I was getting domain errors saying that it was not coming from the same origin...

i.e. `http://www.example.com` & `https://www.example.com` - I don't get **why I would get an error saying not the same origin?** Not to mention I was also using the page with HTTPS (that is what was present in the address bar). Meanwhile while changing the link to HTTP seemed to fix that error.

Comment: You seem to be conflating many issues here. Client Certificates are probably not in your interest at all; you'd knew if you needed that. I have no idea what you want to express with that Paypal screenshot. Last but not least, what you *actually* seem to have an issue with is CORS, not SSL.

Comment: @deceze The purpose of the PayPal screenshot was because I don't see that green bar in the address bar - I do see a green lock, but I don't know if it's the same thing. I can see all of the certificate information, but I wasn't sure if there was something that I am not doing that I should be doing.

Comment: That green bar signifies an *Extended Validation Certificate* is present. That's simply a certificate where the company behind the certificate/website has been vetted more extensively and the information present in the certificate (company name, address etc.) are more trustworthy. You pay more money to obtain such a certificate. It has nothing to do with any settings you can do in the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Require SSL - What exactly does this mean from a client standpoint?

The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732367(v=ws.10).aspx) is a little unclear. It either means:

- When a plain HTTP request is made to the server, it responds saying "The resource you want is at this HTTPS URL, go there to get it" *or*
- It turns off plain HTTP support entirely

This is easy to test if you have an IIS server which supports SSL (I don't) and I would assume it is the first option.

---

> Client Certificates - I get that this all comes from the client, but is it something that I, as a webserver, would issue? What would be a particular situation where you would require a Client certificate?

Generally, you would issue them in the capacity of "someone running a webserver, but possibly also other systems, which require a client certificate".

You use these in lieu of a username/password.

---

> while I do have Require SSL and Ignore Client certificates setup on specific pages, I don't see the below changes to the address bar

It is hard to tell what the issue is when you don't show us what you see on your own site.

---

> i.e. http://www.example.com & https://www.example.com - I don't get why I would get an error saying not the same origin?

The rules for origins are quite strict.

- The hostname must be the same (it is)
- The port must be the same (it isn't, you have 80 and 443, which are the defaults for HTTP and HTTPS)
- The scheme must be the same (HTTP and HTTPS are not the same)

You should mitigate this by using SSL everywhere. Don't use plain HTTP for some things and HTTPS for others.

It's possible that the lack of notification from the browser that the connection is secure (as mentioned in the previous section) is due to you loading other resources over HTTP into the page, but without a test case it is hard to tell.

Comment: This was great, thanks! Answered most of my questions, and deceze covered the address bar issues. I have it setup so that in order to actually login to the website and checkout they need to be using HTTPS, otherwise they get a 403 forbidden access error